# IIS - Required permissions cannot be acquired. Enabled "Full Trust" and Load User Profile on App Pool is "True"

Tags: asp.net, iis

**Setup**

There is an IIS 6 application running in a .NET 2.0 App Pool on Server-A.  IIS 7 Server-B needs to host that same code-base under a different URL.  I created a virtual directory under Server-B's website to the network path of the application on Server-A.  I've enabled this virtual directory on Server-B as an application running in its own .NET 2.0 App Pool in Classic Mode.  Both app pools run as the same domain account that has access to that folder.

**Issue**

When accessing the site from Server-A it works fine.  Accessing it from Server-B however generates the infamous "**Required permissions cannot be acquired.**" error.

I have been trying to find a solution to this problem for two days.  The two most common solutions have been to check the CLR Trust level on the Server-B box or to set the Load User Profile property on the App Pool to "True".  Since I have full administrative rights I set the Trust level to Full and set the profile sitting to "True".  Strongly naming all the assemblies the application and throwing them in the GAC is not where I want to go.

I'm sure I'm just missing some configuration somewhere.  Any ideas?  Thanks.

Comment: I fought with this on and off for the last couple weeks.  Never found a solution.  Changed the deployment scripts to copy updated code to both locations.

Answer (score 1):

We have had a similar problem once.

In our case the user that was the identity of the app pool have never logged on to the server. Therefore, there was no local user profile, therefore there was a problem when the system tried to use the profile.

As a test try and set the identity of the app pool to the admin account you use to log in with.

Comment: Tried logging on as the App Pool user to no avail.  MSDN call here I come.

Answer (score 0):

Manually verify that user can access that share.  Try logging into windows as that user and then accessing that share (or fake it with something like a "runas /User:{Domain\UserName} net use {\server\share}").

Also try loading [ShareMonitor](http://lifehacker.com/5505973/sharemonitor-monitors-and-logs-access-to-windows-shares) wherever the files actually live.  It should tell you what user account is trying to access a given share.  It might not be the account you think it is. I cannot recall if it was this program or not, but I have used something very similar in the past to figure out a really odd permission problem.

That should determine if it is a file access problem.  If it isn't, then all I can say is to make sure you have ASP.NET enabled (on windows server it is a separate option).

Also check out the file permissions on your "Temporary ASP.NET Files" directory.  I've had to explicitly add users write access to that before to get things working.

Comment: Made the app pool's domain account a server administrator on both boxes.  Logged onto both boxes and viewed files both ways.  No dice.  Like I said above, MSDN call time.

Comment: For the `net use` statement, you might want to use `net use \\server\share /user:domain\username`, rather than calling `runas`, by the way  :o)

Answer (score 0):

in my case my IIS App Pool had LoadUserProfile=false, so it was not loading the profile of the app pool's Identify (a domain account). This caused this unable to acquire permissions even though my Webroot files/folders (including /bin) had correct permissions. Setting LoadUserProfile=true fixed the issue for my setup.

Answer (score 0):

I would set that application pools identity attribute (in advanced settings) as administrator. That way, you application will work on the server, just like it works on the local setup.